# How to understand "add up how much of that resource each task requires and divide that into the total quantity available" in deciding thread pool size

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm studying Java Concurrency in Practice, Chap 8.2: Sizing Thread Pools.

The author claims that by dividing *number of all resource needed by tasks* into *quantity of available resources*, we get a upper bound of the thread pool size.

I'm failing to understand this. According to his theory, if our tasks need altogether 4GB memory, and we have 8GB available, the upper bound of thread pool size will be 0.5??

The original paragraph for reference:

> Of course, CPU cycles are not the only resource you might want to manage using thread pools. Other resources that can 
>   contribute  to  sizing  constraints are memory,  file  handles, socket  handles, and database connections.  Calculating pool 
>   size  constraints  for these types of resources  is  easier:  **just add up how much of that resource each task requires and 
>   divide that into the total quantity available.** The result will be an upper bound on the pool size.

Comment: *if our tasks need altogether 4GB* **vs** *add up how much of that resource each task requires*  So if each task needs 1GB of memory then the upper bound should be `8`

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but your equation was essentially inverted.

Let's assume that we have 10 GB of memory available, and each thread requires at most 1 GB of memory.

Without any equations, we can deduce that we can only have at most 10 threads, as that will use a total of 10 GB of memory.

The equation we could use to calculate this is:

```
              Total Quantity Available   10 GB
# Of Tasks =  ------------------------ = ----- = 10
                 Resources Per Task       1 GB
```

Comment: So the statement should actually be "just calculate the maximum quantity of resource each task requires and divide that into the total quantity available"?...